# Understanding Bell's inequality

Tags: quantum-entanglement, bells-inequality

I'm struggling to understand Mermin's article ["Is the moon there when nobody looks?"](http://www-f1.ijs.si/~ramsak/km1/mermin.moon.pdf). In this article, a Bell experiment with three measurement settings is discussed.

Is it possible to reduce the number of measurement settings from 3 to 2? For example, with an experimental setup with two spin detectors, each measuring the spin axis at, say, 90° and and 30°. My understanding is that when both are set to 90°, we'll observe perfect disagreement -- when one device detects `up` the other will always detect `down`. Maybe more importantly, each detector will see `up` and `down` at about the same rate. Now, switch one detector, call it B, to the 30° mode. Is the surprise that detector A, which we didn't touch and left at 90°, sees something other than 50% `up` spin?

Comment: HI, and welcome to Physics StackExchange! It usually a good idea to have your question here self-contained. Even if I am familiar with Bell inequalities, I do not understand your question, presumably because I have not read Mermin’s nine page article. I think it would be much clearer if you explained what the actual set-up is, with its 3 modes of measurements.

Comment: By the way, thanks for the link to Mermin’s article. For people interested, a non-scanned version (but with less pretty figures) is available [here](https://physics.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask).